# How to configure a VPN tunnel using netctl?

Tags: arch-linux, wireguard

In this question, "VPN" shall mean that a tunnel is established to some remote site and all (or most) traffic is routed through this tunnel. Establishing a tunnel using e.g. `wireguard` is documented in the [manual page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/netctl.profile.5.en) and the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/WireGuard). What is missing in both is how to make the tunnel supersede the default route (and give it back when stopping the tunnel). Is that possible in a better way than using hooks? Setting a `Gateway` does not work as the profile is activated when there already is a default gateway configured.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/wg-quick.8.html

Comment: netctl does not use wg-quick. Using wg-quick would likely mean completely bypassing netctl.

Comment: netcl cant config routing needed by wg for you. So it you choice. Just try. wg-quick creates routing and iptables rules to route all traffic via wg tunnel

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1108490/what-do-these-nftables-rules-as-set-up-by-wg-quick-mean